# Javascript floating box in IE 9 not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have an issue with one floating box on my website, this floating box was created with JavaScript (I did not code it myself). The code of this floating box looks like this:

```
<!-- START - popup-box -->

<script type="text/javascript">
var infobox_open = true;
function slide_infobox(){
    if(infobox_open){
        $("#infobox").animate({left:-180},500);
        infobox_open = false;
    }else{
        $("#infobox").animate({left:0},500);
        infobox_open = true;
    }
}
</script>
<div id="infobox" class="infobox_container">
    <div class="infobox_content">
        <float-title>MY TITLE</float-title>

<div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//app.example.com/data/webforms/191361/j171g722op1.js?v12"></script>
</div>
<div>
<a class="povprasevanje" href="http://www.example.com/link/">Pošljite povpraševanje</a>
</div>




    </div>
    <div class="infobox_button" id="infobox_button">
        <a href="javascript:slide_infobox();"><img src="http://www.example.com/infobox_button.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!-- END - popup-box -->
```

In the FF, Opera, Chrome browsers it's displayed properly (see the example [here](http://prnt.sc/dapxft)), but in IE browsers (currently viewing IE 9), that's not the case, as it floats too high. Please see [this image](http://prnt.sc/dapxzg) to see the difference. It works properly in Microsoft Edge browser, though.

I guess the question is: How can I fix this issue, is there anything that should be done with JavaScript code itself in order to IE 9 displaying it properly?

Comment: This looks more like a CSS problem than a JS one

Comment: absolutely position your div, clear any float

Answer (score 0):

This seems as a CSS issue and not JS.

So in your CSS code add this:

```
#infobox {
    position: absolute;  // It should be positioned absolute
    top: 200px; // Or the pixels from top or from relative parent you want
}
```

And it should work. If not please update your code and add your CSS code.